# How to get the print 2 in console. and event is not created but this code is able to print the 1 on console

Tags: javascript

```
//delete the list
itemList.addEventListener('click', removeItem);


//remove item
function removeItem(e){
    console.log(1);
    if(e.target.classList.contains('delete')){
        console.log(2);
        if(confirm('Are You Sure?')){
            console.log(3);
            var li = e.target.preventElement;
            itemList.removeChild('li');
        }
    }
}
```

The code is not working after remove item section. When I see events in inspect section of the browser there is no event created except the DOMcontentloaded. What should I do to make code work?

Comment: breakpoints help debugging. Eventually, instead of `console.log(1);`, use `console.log(e);` and check the content of `e`

Comment: can you provide itemList and HTML code ?